# Adding one record from master-table in addition to other records from detail-table to a MySQL-View

Tags: mysql, view

I am facing a problem creating a MySQL-View. I am not really a pro and i have no clue how to make this work. The situation is the following:
I´ve got a table "Customers" (Master) with all the costumer companies in it and a suitable "Customers_Contacts" (Detail) with all the  company contacts. What i want to do is creating a view with all customer companies and also all of the company contacts.

I am struggling with finding a suitable SQL. I already tried stuff with sub-selects but the result never was the way i wanted it to be.
Here is some (as i hope) explaining material on what my goal is:

```
Customers

+-----+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| ID  | Matchcode  | FirstName | SecondName | Phone      | Email           |
+-----+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| 123 | Mayer GmbH | NULL      | NULL       | 0170/00000 | zentrale@gmx.de |
+-----+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+
...


Customers_Contacts
+-----+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
| ID  | ID_Customer | FirstName | SecondName | Phone      | Email        |
+-----+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
| 111 | 123         | Schmitt   | Else       | 0171/11111 | else@gmx.de  |
| 112 | 123         | Schulz    | Lisa       | 0172/22222 | lisa@gmx.de  |
| 113 | 123         | Marx      | Petra      | 0173/33333 | petra@gmx.de |
+-----+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
...
```

```
v_Customers_Contacts (View)
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Company    | FirstName | SecondName | Phone      | Email           |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+
| Mayer GmbH | NULL      | NULL       | 0170/00000 | zentrale@gmx.de | <-- record from Customers
| Mayer GmbH | Schmitt   | Else       | 0171/11111 | else@gmx.de     |
| Mayer GmbH | Schulz    | Lisa       | 0172/22222 | lisa@gmx.de     |
| Mayer GmbH | Marx      | Petra      | 0173/33333 | petra@gmx.de    |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+
...
```

I really don't know if this is possible with a MySQL-View so please let me know that first.
I´d be really glad if you could post some SQL-code of your ideas how to make this work.

Thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_Customers_Contacts
AS

SELECT a.Matchcode as Company
     , b.FirstName
     , b.SecondName
     , b.Phone
     , b.Email
FROM Customers          as a
JOIN Customers_Contacts as b ON b.ID_Customer = a.ID

UNION

SELECT Matchcode as Company
     , NULL      as FirstName
     , NULL      as SecondName
     , Phone
     , Email
FROM Customers ;
```

When selecting from the view:

```sql
SELECT Company
     , FirstName
     , SecondName
     , Phone
     , Email
FROM v_Customers_Contacts
ORDER BY Company, SecondName, FirstName ;
```